GEE: casting confusionmatrix as list
After reading this question and the corresponding answer, I tried to get a confusion matrix produced by GEE random forrest classifier and turn it into a good looking table. I realized that GEE has a separate object of "ee.ConfusionMatrix" enhanced with a method ".array()" which casts a confusion/error matrix to an array. Consequently one can get the resulting "array" and turn it into a "list":
ee.ConfusionMatrix.array().toList();

The result however is not exactly a list. That is to say when one tries to read the entries of the list:
myList[i][j]

GEE gives an undefined object.
How do I correctly type-cast objects like this confusionMatrix into Lists (list-of-lists)?


The result however is not exactly a list.

Correct - it is a server-side ee.List rather than a client-side list, so you can't directly index into it. Rather than myList[i], you can use myList.get(i) to retrieve the ith element. This returns a server-side representation of whatever is contained in your list. Earth Engine won't know the type of that element until it's retrieved, so you'll need to manually cast it to an ee.List if you want to retrieve an element from it. In other words, instead of myList[i][j], you could write:
ee.List(myList.get(i)).get(j);

A better option here is to avoid the unnecessary list conversion and instead access the element directly from the ee.Array, which has it's own get method:
ee.ConfusionMatrix(...).array().get([i, j]);

